# Calling a Oracle procedure with output variables using OCILIB

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have a procedure with the following signature:

```
procedure countryExists(iCountryName in varchar2, oCount out integer)
```

When I run it using OCILIB, I can't get the right value for oCount. If I register it as integer (using OCI_RegisterInt), I get the error:

> ORA-03116:    invalid buffer length passed to a conversion routine

If I register it as a string, it runs, but OCI_GetString returns a null pointer and OCI_GetInt returns 0 (instead of the expected result 1).

The test code is:

```
int init = OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT|OCI_ENV_CONTEXT);
OCI_Connection *cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("mydb", "myuser", "mypass", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
OCI_Statement *st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);

int resultprepare = OCI_Prepare(st, "call mypackage.countryExists('BRAZIL', :oCount)");
//int registercount = OCI_RegisterString(st, ":oCount", 100);
int registercount= OCI_RegisterInt(st, ":oCount");
int executeresult = OCI_Execute(st);
OCI_Error *err1 = OCI_GetLastError();
const char *error1 = OCI_ErrorGetString(err1);
OCI_Resultset *resultset = OCI_GetResultset(st);
const wchar_t *valstr = OCI_GetString(resultset, 1);
int valint = OCI_GetInt(resultset, 1);
OCI_Error *err2 = OCI_GetLastError();
const char *error2 = OCI_ErrorGetString(err2);
```

Running the procedure using, for example, PL/SQL Developer works fine.

Is this the right way of calling procedures using OCILIB?

Also note that I'm using the mixed version of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not coding in Java....

Here is the right way to do it :

```
OCI_Connection *cn;
OCI_Statement  *st;
int count;

OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT|OCI_ENV_CONTEXT);

cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("mydb", "myuser", "mypass", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);

OCI_Prepare(st, "begin mypackage.countryExists('BRAZIL', :oCount); end;");
OCI_BindInt(st, ":oCount", &count);
OCI_Execute(st);
```

Check the OCILIB documentation and/or manual

Vincent